# WinSCP closes; server exit status 254; "Your shell is probably incompatible with the application"

Tags: centos, scp

WinSCP 5.5.3 (build 4214)
CentOS GNU/Linux 2.6.32-642.15.1.el6.x86_64
Login configuration: SCP protocol, port 22, everything else is default.

The error:
Connection has been unexpectedly closed.
Server sent command exit status 254.
Error skipping startup message. Your shell is probably incompatible with the application (BASH is recommended).

`getent` on the remote Unix server reports that my login shell is indeed /bin/bash, which does exist with perms 755.

I've looked all over the WinSCP help forum for a solution. Nothing there makes any sense - in most cases, I can't even parse the replies to the person having the error.

I tried looking up "scp server status 254", and found a tip here to turn off PAM (in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, set "UsePAM" to "no"). Same error.

What more can I do to diagnose this problem?

Comment: it could be that one of your shell profiles is emitting output that's confusing the scp connection; try temporarily moving them aside to see if that affects the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Checked with a local sysadmin, and found that there was a security policy in place that limited everyone to three TTYs. Once I closed all but two, WinSCP connected properly.

(I'm now debating whether to ask why a limit on TTYs makes sense, but that's another story.)

(Also, I'd like to know how to find out that this is the limitation, from a "254" error.)